# Django: Image field does not display and is not uploaded into target repo

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and got this problem:

- **ImageField does not display** (while other fields display well)
- **When uploading, new image is not uploaded into target repo**

What I have:

- **Target repo** containing default image and future upload images.
  Repo name: media.
  Repo structure: on the same level with manage.py
- Code in **settings.py**:

  ```
  MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

  MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
  ```
- Code in **models.py**

  ```
  class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

      image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='images/', blank=True)
      phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
      bio = models.TextField(null=True)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.username
  ```
- Code in **forms.py**:

  ```
  class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

      class Meta:
          model = CustomUser
          fields = ['username', 'email', 'image', 'phone_number', 'bio']
  ```
- Code in **html**:

  ```
  {% extends 'base.html' %}

  {% block content %}
  <h2>User Account View</h2>
  <div id="User">
      <img src="media/{{ User.image }}">

      <ul>
          <li>{{ User.username }}</li>
          <li>{{ User.email }}</li>
          <li>{{ User.phone_number }}</li>
          <li>{{ User.bio }}</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  {% endblock %}
  ```

I have researched on many sources and asked few mentors, but still have no luck.
Please help if you can

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
<p><img src="{{ item.file.url }}"></p>
```